# modelica: modifying array parameter in array of components

Tags: arrays, modelica

Hello I want to be able to make the following modification:

```
Zone.ZONE[nZones] MultiZone(
    nMONOL={{nMONOL[i] for i in (1:nSURFS[j])} for j in 1:nZones});
```

with nZones = 2

with nSURFS = {2,4}

with nMONOL = {5,4,6,7,8,9}

.

The result should be:

MultiZone[1].nMONOL[2] = {5,4}

MultiZone[2].nMONOL[3] = {6,7,8,9}

But the modification above does not work. Is there a way to make it work?
Kind Regards
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions that may be sufficient for your purposes. As described by the syntax of your question there is a package `Zone` which contains a model `ZONE`. The `example` model is then what was presented in your question.

## Approach #1

A couple notes

- `fixed=false` allows the definition of nMONOL in an initial algorithm/equation section
- `sum(nSURFS[1:i-1])` is generic to the number of `nSURFS` specified.
- Instead of specifing nZones you could have that be dependent on `nSURFS`. Depends on what is actually occuring with your code though if that makes sense.

  i.e., `parameter Integer nZones = size(nSURFS,1)`

**The code is as follows:**

```
package Zone

  model ZONE

    parameter Integer nSURFS = 2;
    parameter Integer nMONOL[nSURFS](fixed=false); // Notice the modification

  end ZONE;

  model example

    parameter Integer nZones=2;
    parameter Integer nSURFS[nZones]={2,4};
    parameter Integer nMONOL[sum(nSURFS)]={5,4,6,7,8,9};

    Zone.ZONE[nZones] MultiZone(nSURFS=nSURFS);

  initial algorithm // or initial equation 

    for i in 1:nZones loop
      for j in 1:nSURFS[i] loop
        MultiZone[i].nMONOL[j] := nMONOL[j + sum(nSURFS[1:i-1])];
      end for;
    end for;

  end example;

end Zone;
```

**Producing the desired result:**

MultiZone[1].nMONOL[2] = {5,4}

MultiZone[2].nMONOL[4] = {6,7,8,9}

## Approach #2

Talked with a friend to get inspired for an alternative approach.

This second approach is an attempt get around the language restriction that type arrays have the same length (at least when you are trying to define them inline). To do so, rely on a matrix where `0` or some other value that makes sense pads the matrix. Internal to the model you can then have a internal (`_int`) parameter to help clarify what you are using. But that is not necessary so long as you ensure any loops, etc. are keyed to go from 1:nSURFS (i.e., the 0 values will never be used.

Also the note about nZones in Approach #1 still applies if desired.

```
package Zone
  model ZONE

    parameter Integer nSURFS = integer(if Modelica.Math.Vectors.find(0,nMONOL) == 0 then size(nMONOL,1) else Modelica.Math.Vectors.find(0,nMONOL)-1);
    parameter Integer nMONOL[:];
    final parameter Integer nMONOL_int[nSURFS] = {nMONOL[i] for i in 1:nSURFS};

  end ZONE;

  model example

    parameter Integer nZones=2;
    parameter Integer nMONOL[nZones,:]={{5,4,0,0},{6,7,8,9}};

    Zone.ZONE[nZones] MultiZone(nMONOL = nMONOL);

  end example;
end Zone;
```

**Producing the desired result:**

MultiZone[1].nMONOL[4] = {5,4,0,0}

MultiZone[1].nMONOL_int[2] = {5,4}

MultiZone[2].nMONOL[4] = {6,7,8,9}

MultiZone[2].nMONOL_int[4] = {6,7,8,9}

## Approach #3

A slightly simpler version of Approach #2. Note, be sure that when using nMONOL in a `ZONE` type that you loop over nSURFS, or create an internal variable so as to not use the `0` values.

```
package Zone
  model ZONE

    parameter Integer nSURFS;
    parameter Integer nMONOL[:];

  end ZONE;

  model example

    parameter Integer nZones=2;
    parameter Integer nSURFS[:] = {2, 4};
    parameter Integer nMONOL[nZones,max(nSURFS)]={{5,4,0,0},{6,7,8,9}};

    Zone.ZONE[nZones] MultiZone(nSURFS = nSURFS, nMONOL = nMONOL);

  end example;
end Zone;
```

Comment: Although the desired result was produced, it also resulted in another problem. The idea behind the question was to use the MultiZone[i].nMONOL vectors to define another array of components:


**for i in 1:size(nMONOL,1) loop
  MultiZone.Wall[ nMONOL[i] ] Wall1
end for;**

Modelica does not like array of components with non-fixed size...

Comment: Indeed that is a limitation of this solution. Honestly I am surprised at the restriction imposed, not sure though if it is a language spec or a artificial IDE restriction that prevents defining arrays of different size inline (which I attempted as well and couldn't get working - I'm using Dymola). If I learn anything more about that I'll try to come back here but seems like it is best to come up with an alternative approach... You might be able to do something "fancy" with intermediate `final parameters`. Not sure though

Comment: The non-fixed size for arrays should only occur for approach 1, and you should be able to use nMONOL_int from approach 2 to define an array of components with Wall-vectors of different lengths. However, I might be missing something.